# How to send a text to email address without sender and server in python

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I have a text message which I want to send it to the email address without any mail id. I have only the receiver's email id without a port.

How can i do this in python.

```
import smtplib
TO = 'test@gmail.com'
MSG = "Hello"
server.sendmail(TO, MSG)

server.quit()
print ("Email Send")
```

just I have to send the text to email.

Comment: you have to set a sender email-id and password

Comment: @MohammadAarif just i dont want to include any senders adress just i have to send the text to receivers address thats it